# Show notification when cell value/outcome changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code such that a Message box pops up whenever the value inside certain cells change.

The cells that I want to monitor change because they are linked to a query which is refreshed automatically. The VBA codes I found online only work when the cell value is changed manually, this will not work because the formula in the cells do not change, only the displayed value changes.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The worksheet_change event only triggers if a cell value changes manually (or by vba), but it doesn't trigger by a formula change or something similar. Therefore the only event that you could use is the `Worksheet_Calculate` which triggers on any cell calculation, but this has no `Target` cell. So what you ask for does not exist there is one that workaround to get somehow close to it.

Comment: So the workaround would be to save the value you want to observe as a copy somewhere else. And on every  `Worksheet_Calculate` you compare the copy with the pontentially updated value. If it changed throw a message and make a new copy so you can trigger the next change. Give it a try. If you get stuck or errors come back, show your code and ask a question to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Application Calculate (Public Variables)

- The following is written for a non-contiguous range.
- A message box pop's up each time a value in the range changes via formula.
- Copy the codes into the appropriate modules.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- This is an automated solution. To start you should either save, close, and reopen the workbook or run the `popupMsgBoxInit` procedure.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const popupWsName As String = "Sheet1"
Public Const popupRgAddress As String = "A1,C3,E5"
Public popupRg As Range
Public popupCount As Long
Public popupArr As Variant

Sub popupMsgBoxInit()
    Set popupRg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(popupWsName).Range(popupRgAddress)
    popupRg.Interior.Color = 65535 'xlNone
    popupCount = popupRg.Cells.Count
    ReDim popupArr(1 To popupCount)
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cel In popupRg.Cells
        i = i + 1
        popupArr(i) = cel.Value
    Next cel
End Sub

Sub popupMsgBox()
    Dim chCount As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each cel In popupRg.Cells
        i = i + 1
        If cel.Value <> popupArr(i) Then
            chCount = chCount + 1
            popupArr(i) = cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
    MsgBox "Number of Changes: " & chCount, vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    popupMsgBoxInit
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    popupMsgBox
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I eventually created a table with a copy of the values of the cells in question. 

Then every Worksheet_Calculate the macro compares the cells in question with the table and if it doesn't match, the macro throws a notification and overwrites the value in the table with the current cell value.